# Constructing input for TensorFlow's high-level estimator

Tags: c++, machine-learning, tensorflow

A high-level estimator (e.g., `tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor`) is trained and saved in Python (using `export_savedmodel` with `serving_input_fn`). It is then loaded from C++ (using `LoadSavedModel`) for predictions. According to `saved_model_cli` the input tensor expected is of `shape: (-1)` and `dtype: DT_STRING`.

I can define such input tensor by constructing a tensorflow::Example object and then serialize it as string. However, I wonder if there are **more efficient ways to do that?** (That is, assuming the inputs are a bunch of floats, then building an object, defining feature map, serializing to string and then parsing it seems wasteful when this is done millions+ times.)