# How to feed inputs into a loaded Tensorflow model using C++

Tags: tensorflow

I want to create and train a model, export it and run inference in C++.

I'm following the tutorial listed here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide_and_deep

I'm also trying to use the **SavedModel** approach as described here since this is the canonical way to export TensorFlow graphs for serving:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/saved_model/README.md.

At the very end, I export the saved model as follows:

```
feature_spec = tf.contrib.layers.create_feature_spec_for_parsing(feature_columns)     
serving_input_fn = input_fn_utils.build_parsing_serving_input_fn(feature_spec)    
output = model.export_savedmodel(model_dir, serving_input_fn, as_text=True)                       
print('Model saved to {}'.format(output))
```

I see the saved_model.pbtxt has the following signature definition.

```
signature_def {
  key: "serving_default"
  value {
    inputs {
      key: "inputs"
      value {
        name: "input_example_tensor:0"
        dtype: DT_STRING
        tensor_shape {
          dim {
            size: -1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  outputs { 
  ...
```

I can load the saved model on the C++ side

```
SavedModelBundle bundle;                                        

const std::string graph_path = "models/1498572863";            
const std::unordered_set<std::string> tags = {"serve"};         

Status status = LoadSavedModel(session_options,                        
                        run_options, graph_path,               
                        tags, &bundle);
```

I'm stuck at the last part where I need to feed the input into this model. 
The Run function expects the input parameter to be of the form: `std::vector<std::pair<string, Tensor>>`.

I would have expected this to be a vector of pairs where the key is the feature name used in the python code and the Tensor is multiple values for that feature.

However, it seems to expect the string to be "input_example_tensor". 
I'm not sure how I'm supposed to now feed the model with different features using a single Tensor.

```
std::vector<string> output_tensor_names = {
"binary_logistic_head/_classification_output_alternatives/classes_tensor"};

// How do I create input_tensor?
status = bundle.session->Run({{"input_example_tensor", input_tensor}}
    output_tensor_names, {}, &outputs);
```

**Solution**

I did something like this

```
tensorflow::Example example;
auto& tf_feature_map = *(example.mutable_features()->mutable_feature());

tf_feature_map["name"].mutable_int64_list()->add_value(15);
const std::string& serialized = example.SerializeAsString();
tensorflow::Input input({serialized});

status = bundle.session->Run({{"input_example_tensor", input.tensor()}}
    output_tensor_names, {}, &outputs);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44146465/constructing-input-for-tensorflows-high-level-estimator suggests using a tensorflow::Example and serializing it.

This is similar to the approach in tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader_test.cc.

That seems extremely unintuitive .. and undocumented :)

Comment: How does one convert the serialized tensorflow::Example into an input tensor?

Comment: That does thanks.
I did something like this

`
tensorflow::Example example;
auto& tf_feature_map = *(example.mutable_features()->mutable_feature());

tf_feature_map["name"].mutable_int64_list()->add_value(15);
const std::string& serialized = example.SerializeAsString();
tensorflow::Input input({serialized});

status = bundle.session->Run({{"input_example_tensor", input.tensor()}}
    output_tensor_names, {}, &outputs);
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model signature suggests that it is expecting a `DT_STRING` tensor as input. When using `tensorflow::Example`, this typically means that the protocol buffer needs to be serialized into a tensor with a string as the type of its elements.

To convert the `tensorflow::Example` object to a string, you can use the protocol buffer methods such as [`SerializeToString`, `SerializeAsString` etc.](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message_lite#MessageLite.SerializeToString.details)

Hope that helps.